# Fail to Deploy Simple Solidity Contract via Remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Why does Remix fail to deploy the simple contract (simplified from the Mastering Ethereum book https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/code/Solidity/Faucet2.sol )? --

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Faucet {
    function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public {
        require(withdraw_amount <= 100000000000000000);
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
    }

    function () external payable {}
}
```

No matter how I raise gasLimit and/or gasPrice

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine (I have also tried it myself). From what I see above you are also sending a value along with the deploy. Since you have not defined a constructor yourself the default one is being called which is not payable. If you want to send ether when you deploy the contract you should also define a payable constructor.

Comment: So were you able to deploy the _exact_ code with Remix? If you had to make modification for it to be deploy-able, what did you change?

Comment: Yes, the exact same code. As I said you must set the value to `0 ether` when you deploy since you do not have a payable constructor.

Comment: You right. I totally confused the "Value" on the Remix interface with gasPrice.